# Add a pandas column called age based on existing DOB column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column called DOB which has dates formatted 31.07.1983 for example.

My data frame is named users_pd.

I want to add a column that has the current age of the customer based off the existing DOB column.

from datetime import date, timedelta

users_pd["Age"] = (date.today() - users_pd["DOB"] // timedelta(days=365.2425))

I get the error

```
TypeError: Invalid dtype object for __floordiv__
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert column to datetime and then convert timedeltas to `year`s:

```
users_pd["DOB"] = pd.to_datetime(users_pd["DOB"], format='%d.%m.%Y')

users_pd["Age"] = (pd.to_datetime('today') - users_pd["DOB"]).astype('<m8[Y]').astype(int)
```

Comment: When I try to run the first line of code it has this error:
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @CeePee - Answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis was incorrectly placed, and you probably failed to convert to datetime.

Use:

```
users_pd["Age"] = (pd.Timestamp('today')
                 - pd.to_datetime(users_pd["DOB"], dayfirst=True)
                  ) // pd.Timedelta(days=365.2425)
```

Example:

```
          DOB  Age
0  31.07.1983   39
```